# Using macros as keys for GetTranslation

Tags: translations

Why does the following code not produce two lines of text with the single word "baz" each? (Instead there is only one line for the direct call to `GetTranslation`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{translations}

\DeclareTranslationFallback {foo-bar}{baz}
\DeclareTranslation{English}{foo-bar}{baz}

\newcommand{\asdf}[1]{
  \edef\translationkey{foo-#1}%
  \GetTranslation{\translationkey}
}

\begin{document}

\GetTranslation{foo-bar}

\asdf{bar}

\end{document}
```

I suppose it has something to do with when macros are evaluated.

Comment: `\expandafter\GetTranslation\expandafter{\translationkey}` -- you must expand the `\translationkey` first before feeding it to `\GetTranslation`

Comment: I guess your MWE is a simplification of the real use case? Otherwise you get the same thing easier: `\newcommand{\asdf}[1]{\GetTranslation{foo-#1}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the argument `\translationkey` must be expanded in order to be digested by `\GetTranslation`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{translations}

\DeclareTranslationFallback {foo-bar}{baz}
\DeclareTranslation{English}{foo-bar}{baz}

\newcommand{\asdf}[1]{%
  \edef\translationkey{foo-#1}%
  \expandafter\GetTranslation\expandafter{\translationkey}%
}

\begin{document}

\GetTranslation{foo-bar}

\asdf{bar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Even though it was just an internet search away, after reading this answer, a link explaining the why and how: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/expandafter

Comment: The definition of `\asdf` has two spurious spaces…

Comment: @clemens Thank you for pointing that out.  Fixed.